# How to I connect a search form field with an API GET request? (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, api

On my home page, I have the html form:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="condition" placeholder="condition" value="condition" />
   <input type="submit" value="search NOW" class="search-btn" />
</form>
```

On the page that needs to return the results (/yacht-search), I have the wp_remote_get call:

```
$response = wp_remote_get('http://data.yatco.com/dataservice/APIKEY/search' );
```

How do I link the two so that when the user enters the condition ("new" for example) - it connects to the API and returns the results?

I've tested the API call in Postman and it returns the data just fine -  I just am having trouble connecting the dots so it outputs the results onto the page..

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = wp_remote_get('http://data.yatco.com/dataservice/APIKEY/search' );
$api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure that had any effect. The URL in question is evolution.losomoinc.com. If you type "new" into the search box for the condition, it should take you to the results page with that parameter - but nothing shows..what am I missing?

Comment: Out of a 100 possiblities, I would say you are not forming the request properly. But that's just 1 out of a 100.

Comment: I know...there's so many things that could be wrong, and I just have no idea. The request is based just on what I found in the codex regarding get requests.